# Converting cURL Multi-Form to Python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

In cURL this works fine:

```
curl 'https://api.flaticon.com/v3/app/authentication' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-F apikey=PRIVATE_KEY

Response:
{"data":{"token":"TOKEN","expires":1680693480}}`
```

This Python code with the exact same PRIVATE_KEY throws 403 and for the life of me I cannot figure out why:

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
  'apikey': (None, 'PRIVATE_KEY'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api.flaticon.com/v3/app/authentication', headers=headers, files=files)

print(response)
```

Comment: Found it! Turns out I need to set the header like so:  Headers= { 'user-agent': 'curl/7.86.0', ...} The 403 was thrown due to "wrong" header :/

Answer (score 0):

cURL's `-F` is not `file`, but `form`; that maps to `requests.post(..., data=...)`.

Chances are you don't need the `multipart/form-data` header either.

```
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://api.flaticon.com/v3/app/authentication',
    headers=headers,
    data={'apikey': 'PRIVATE_KEY'},
)
```

Comment: I tried this, doesn't help though. Thanks for the speedy reply anyway :)